# How to create a database directory structure for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, sql, ruby-on-rails

I was following this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

So far, I installed *mysql-server* *mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev*, and I was suppose to tell MySQL to create its database directory structure where it will store its information using `sudo mysql_install_db`.

```
$ sudo mysql_install_db

[WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize
[ERROR]   The data directory needs to be specified.
```

I thought running `mysqld --initialize` would solve the issue:

```
$ mysqld --initialize 

mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 17 - File exists)
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
[ERROR] Aborting
```

How do I tell MySQL to create its database directory structure where it will store its information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using a previously answered question, 
[How to install mysql on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787342/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04), but I needed to modify the solution to work for me.

When I deleted/moved `/var/lib/mysql` directory, `mysqld --initialize` couldn't create the database directory I want in replacement for `/var/lib/mysql` , and it gave me `Errcode: 13 - Permission denied` even though I preceded it with `sudo`.

I deleted/moved the content of `/var/lib/mysql/`, but not the directory itself. I tried again to run `sudo mysql --initialize`, and it worked, and created new content within the `/var/lib/mysql/` directory. The content produced by `mysql --initialize` is different than the previous content I deleted/moved.

I continued the rest of the steps in the tutorial, and worked perfectly.

P.S. I needed to use `sudo -i` to access `/var/lib/mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the entire solution for your problem.

According to [fromdual](https://www.fromdual.com/node/1279), the suggestion is to just follow the
advice of the error. Some functionality is being deprecated.

> Our advice is to enable the variable explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
> now on your testing systems so you can see if your application behave
> well and then you are prepared for the next release when this feature
> will become the default.
>
> In short term this warning is NOT dangerous. In the long term you
> have to be prepared for the deprecated functionality. You get rid of
> the warning my setting explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1 in your
> my.cnf [mysqld] section.

You can [find the `my.cnf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758/5986651) file in the following locations, and in
this order the values override each other:

- /etc/my.cnf
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
- [datadir]/my.cnf
- ~/.my.cnf

You can also [find your file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2482474/5986651) by

```
find / -name my.cnf
```

I added the following in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
```

Now try

```
mysqld --initialize
```

And I got a reduced error without Timestamp stuff

```
mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 17 - File exists)
2018-11-12T20:13:45.024116Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Is this good? Not sure so I look deeper. According to the above[accepted stack
answer for the error](https://askubuntu.com/a/797696/443958) you need to

```
sudo -i #log into root
cd /var/lib/mysql
rm -r *

su username  # get back to the original user

mysqld --initialize
```

This, still gave me the exact same error. No change!

```
mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 17 - File exists)
2018-11-12T20:13:45.024116Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I am not sure the above accepted answer helped at all with the removing the
`/var/lib/mysql`, but `sudo` helped:

```
sudo mysqld --initialize
```

worked... No error at all!

Comment: first solution doesn't work for me, and this also doesn't work for me :(