# What is the proper way to install mysql in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I wanted to install mysql on my laptop to use in projects where I need a database.
I'm confused, because I've seen some questions on this site: [How to install mysql on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787342/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04)
But I do not know where to find mysql.
Can you tell me the steps to follow?
Thank you.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly the three points which are spoken about in the other thread is correct

1. Install mysql-server

Better upgrade the system first:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the system upgrade install mysql-server

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

2. Create a mysql root user. Normally the system should ask you for a root user password, which will be the admin password for your DB.
3. If this is not the case, or you'd like to change it, the following command should be helpful.

   sudo mysql_secure_installation

Comment: Finally I could install. I had to repeat the steps followed to sudo mysql_secure_installation and first do them wrong. Thanks for your help. I must also thank @KGR for their link showed me helped me understand the configuration form. Thank you